Integer solutions to a Diophantine equation $2(q^2+s^2)(p^2+r^2)=(p^2-r^2)^2+(q^2-s^2)^2=(2pr)^2+(2qs)^2$
I am trying to solve this Diophantine equation to find integer solutions but not succeed I need help to find integer solutions for
$2(q^2+s^2)(p^2+r^2)=(p^2-r^2)^2+(q^2-s^2)^2=(2pr)^2+(2qs)^2$

Let the common expression equal $X$. Then
$$2X = (p^2-r^2)^2+(q^2-s^2)^2+(2pr)^2+(2qs)^2 = (p^2+r^2)^2+(q^2+s^2)^2,$$
$$(p^2+r^2)^2+(q^2+s^2)^2 = 2X = 4(q^2+s^2)(p^2+r^2).$$
With $a = p^2+r^2$ and $b = q^2+s^2$ we have
$$a^2+b^2 = 4ab.$$
If either variable is $0$ then the other is as well giving the trivial zero-solution for $p, q, r, s$. Otherwise we define $t = \frac{a}{b}$ rational and get
$$t^2-4t+1 = 0$$
so $t = 2\pm \sqrt{3}$, which is not rational. Thus the only solution is the all-zero solution.

Nice solution! (+1) If it was me getting $a^2+b^2=4ab$, I would(not simple as you, but) let $a=2a_0, b=2b_0$(since $a^2+b^2 \equiv 0 (\mod 4)$) then use method of infinite descent.
